# Loader on a link ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to do something very simple, but it doesn't work for all browser... 
I need your help here :

```
<a href="@(Url.Action("Accept", "Manager", new { HolidayId = item.HolidayId }))" class="uifw-button xsmall black" OnClick="loader()"><i class="uifw-icon-standard uifw-icon-standard-check-circle xsmall " ></i>Accept</a>
```

Here is a simple button, When I click on, it gonna send an Email to user with data from database.

The fact is, if I press on this button few times, it's gonna send few mails.

So, I'd like to put a loader or something like this, so the user know he have to wait few secs, and he won't be able to click on that link again.

I tried something like this but that's not working.. I'm really new with JS..

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                (function loader() {
                        getElementById('loading').style.display ='block';
                }(document));
            </script>



           <div id="loading">
                <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>
```

Edit : Ok I just updated my code and I have this :

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
                function ShowSendingProgress() {
                    var modal = $('<div  />');
                    modal.addClass("modal");
                    modal.attr("id", "modalSending");
                    $('body').append(modal);
                    var loading = $("#modalSending.loading");
                    loading.show();
                    var top = '215px';
                    var left = '560px';
                    loading.css({ top: top, left: left, color: '#ffffff' });

                }
            </script>



            <div class="loading" id="modalSending" align="center">
                <img src="~/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
            </div>


  <a href="@(Url.Action("Accept", "Manager", new { HolidayId = item.HolidayId }))" class="uifw-button xsmall black" OnClick="ShowSendingProgress()"><i class="uifw-icon-standard uifw-icon-standard-check-circle xsmall "></i>Accept</a>
```

That's not working, I see the ajax loader even if I don't click on the link..

Thanks for helping,

Comment: Have you tried something that didn't work for you or are you asking someone to solve it for you?

Comment: use actionlink instead...

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla I can't use ActionLink here, because I want this inside : <i class="uifw-icon-standard uifw-icon-standard-check-circle xsmall "></i>

Comment: @MichalB. I'll show you what I did and Edit my post in fews min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the loader hidden, that should solve your problem:

`<div class="loading" id="modalSending" align="center" style="display:none">`

Comment: Cool, can you accept the answer then? 
Regarding the modal dialog, have a look [here](http://blog.raventools.com/create-a-modal-dialog-using-css-and-javascript/).